# How do I download a Jsoup Document from a website asynchronously and then notify the UI thread when complete?

Tags: java, android, html, multithreading, asynchronous

In my Android app, when a user clicks a button, I want it to execute this the below code asynchronously and and then somehow get the `Document` back to the UI thread when it has completed executing.  Ideally I'd like it to fire off an event on the UI thread so that I can do some operations on the document.

```
Document doc = Jsoup.connect(urls[0].toString()).get();
```

I'm really not sure the best way to go about this.  I'm looking at an AsyncTask, but I can't figure out a clean way to get the Document back to the UI thread.

FYI, I am new to Java.  I am mostly a .NET developer, and boy would I love to have a BackgroundWorker right about now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, AsyncTask is the right way, after download it, the UI thread will call your code.

```
 protected void onPostExecute(Long result) {
     showDialog("Download ok");
 }
```

see the [document](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/AsyncTask.html).